# FCM push notification error: Message must be a non-null object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement FCM push notifications in a react.js app using Cloud functions for the first time and stuck at this error: Message must be a non-null object. I've read some answers that provide on this topic but non of them helped me. I don't know what is exactly wrong with my code.
Here's my index.js inside the functions dir

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const sendNotifications = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}').onCreate(
    async (snapshot) => {
        const text = snapshot.data().text;
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `${snapshot.data().username} sent ${text ? 'a new message' : 'a new attachment'}`,
                body: text ? (text.length <= 100 ? text : text.substring(0, 97) + '...') : '',
                icon: snapshot.data().photoURL || '/images/profile_placeholder.png',
            }
        };
        console.log("Payload", payload)

        // Get the list of device tokens
        const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').get();
        const tokens = [];
        allTokens.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
            tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
        });

        console.log(tokens)

        // Send notification to all tokens.
        if (tokens.length > 0) {
            // Send notifications to all tokens.
            const response = await admin.messaging().send(tokens, payload);
            await cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
            functions.logger.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
        } else{
            console.log("Not tokens", tokens)
        }
    }
);


// Cleans up the tokens that are no longer valid.
function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {
    // For each notification we check if there was an error.
    const tokensDelete = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            functions.logger.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
            // Cleanup the tokens that are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                const deleteTask = admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').doc(tokens[index]).delete();
                tokensDelete.push(deleteTask);
            }
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensDelete);
}
```

When I log the payload to the console it display the notification object with all the data in it which confuses me because it's not null, it's an object with data inside of it.
Below is a screenshot for the log output.
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the log output so we can see exactly what you see. Also, for clarity, you show which line of code causes the error.

Comment: According to the error stack, line 34 is is the one causing the error. The following line: const response = await admin.messaging().send(tokens, payload);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the Fireabse Admin API correctly.  It doesn't take the arguments that you're passing.  Please take another look at the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsend) and [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) to learn about how it works.

If you want to send a message to multiple devices, you should use [sendMulticast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsendmulticast) or [sendEachForMulticast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsendeachformulticast) instead of send(). It accepts a [MulticastMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.multicastmessage.md#multicastmessage_interface) object which contains the tokens to send to. There is an example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices):

```
// Create a list containing up to 500 registration tokens.
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
const registrationTokens = [
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // …
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_N',
];

const message = {
  data: {score: '850', time: '2:45'},
  tokens: registrationTokens,
};

getMessaging().sendMulticast(message)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my code and used sendEachForMulticast() instead of send() and it worked. Note: sendMulticast() is deprecated.